# Why does assigning a variable of type any change the type of the variable it is assigned to?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, any

Let's look at the following example:

```
let a: string = "hello world"
let b: number = 23
let c: any = 23

console.log(typeof a) // "string"
console.log(typeof b) // "number"
console.log(typeof c) // "number"

a = b // Fails!
a = c // Works!
console.log(typeof a) // "number"

a = b // Fails!
a = "Hallo Welt" // Works!
console.log(typeof a) // "string"
```

1. Why is it possible to change the type of a non-any variable? I would expect `x: any = y: string | number | ...`, but not `x: string | number | ... = y: any`, except if the any variable is inferenced to a matching type.
2. Why can I assign a string after "changing" the type to number, but no number?
3. How do I prevent a variable from ever changing its type.

Comment: Change your build to not allow any?

Comment: `c` is `any`, so as far as the compiler is concerned it _is_ a `number` (and a `string`, and everything else). `a = c` therefore doesn't change the type of `a` **at compile time** (what you're seeing via `console.log(typeof thing)` is the **runtime type**). A more conservative type for `c` would be `unknown`, which you couldn't assign without further checking.

Comment: You faced with consequences of `any` usage. Varible redefining via `a = b` where _any_ variable is `any`, make _all_ of them `any`. So try to avoid `any` at all.

Answer (score 1):

According to [TypeScript Documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#any):

> **Don’t** use `any` as a type unless you are in the process of migrating a JavaScript project to TypeScript. The compiler effectively treats `any` as “please turn off type checking for this thing”. It is similar to putting an `@ts-ignore` comment around every usage of the variable. This can be very helpful when you are first migrating a JavaScript project to TypeScript as you can set the type for stuff you haven’t migrated yet as `any`, but in a full TypeScript project you are disabling type checking for any parts of your program that use it.
>
> In cases where you don’t know what type you want to accept, or when you want to accept anything because you will be blindly passing it through without interacting with it, you can use [unknown](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#example/unknown-and-never).

```js
let a: string = "hello world"
let b: number = 23
let c: unknown = 23

console.log(typeof a) // "string"
console.log(typeof b) // "number"
console.log(typeof c) // "number"

a = b // Fails!
a = c // Fails!
a = "Hallo Welt" //Works!
```